# Nontechnical Proof of “Puzzle on coins: Designing an operation”

Tags: puzzle

[Previously asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557607/puzzle-on-coins-designing-an-operation):

> A square table has a coin at each corner. Design an execution
>   sequence, each of whose steps consists of one of the following
>   operations:
>
> ONE (O): The operation (randomly) chooses a coin and flips it. SIDE
>   (S): The operation (randomly) chooses a side of the table and flips
>   the two coins along that side. DIAG (D): The operation (randomly)
>   chooses a diagonal of the table and flips the two coins along that
>   diagonal.
>
> such that at some point during the execution (not necessarily at the
>   end), a state where all coins are turned the same way (all heads or
>   all tails) obtains.

The desired answer is O, D, S, D, O, D, S, D.

Is there a **non-technical proof** of this answer, and how one may arrive at it?

Comment: What would you consider to be a "non-technical proof"?

Comment: An answer that a curious (curious enough to try this puzzle) would have a fair chance to understand.

Comment: Have you seen http://kedargodbole.blogspot.com.au/2008/07/puzzle-table-with-four-coins.html ?

Comment: I did. It may be my incompetence, but I don't see it self-evident as a _proof_.

Comment: A variation of the problem is discussed, and some references given, at http://gurmeet.net/puzzles/tumblers-on-a-rotating-table/

Comment: Also, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_glasses_puzzle

Comment: [The article provided in Wikipedia](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~jrge/Papers/BBP.pdf)  _hints_ that there may not be a non-technical _proof_.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the answer, so a non-technical proof might be simply checking the answer.

First write down every possible starting condition on a piece of paper. Then for each starting position write down every possible result of the first operation on another piece of paper. Then for each result on that piece of paper, write down every possible result of the second operation on yet another piece of paper. Do this for each step, and check that every end result is the desired outcome.

It is simple, but it may take a long time and use a lot of paper. Perhaps in the process you will notice a pattern that helps you understand the more technical proofs.